# I have this error that saying "unexpected type required variable .. " in java. Can someone help me with this?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error

```
interface Air_flight {

    public final int passenger_number = 100;
 
}
```

....
....

```
class CancelTicket extends Flight {

    public CancelTicket(int no) {
        super();
        passenger_list.size() = passenger_list.size() - no;
    }

}//end of CancelTicket class
```

Comment: the error is in         passenger_list.size() = passenger_list.size() - no;

Comment: You are trying to update size of list by assigning it. Are you sure?

Comment: Is `passenger_list` a `List` and are you trying to delete an element from it?

Comment: Where do you define passenger_list?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove an element (the airline ticket number) from the list, then you should do it like this:

```
Integer ticketNumber = new Integer(no);
int index;
while ((index = passenger_list.indexOf(ticketNumber)) >= 0) {
    passenger_list.remove(index);
}
```

You can't re-assign the size of the list the way you're doing (you can only GET the size of a list). If you want to reduce the size, you need to remove elements from the list. And then, when you call the size() method again after removing elements from the list, you will see that the size is smaller at that point.